# escape some fileds which are dart keyword

Tags: flutter, dart, built-value

in my application which i connected to server, that return this output:

```dart
"usertags": {
    "in": [
        {

        }
    ]
},
```

in that `in` is dart keyword and i don't how can i escape that to get data from that and i get this error:

> error: Expected a class member.

```dart
abstract class BuiltUserTags implements Built<BuiltUserTags, BuiltUserTagsBuilder> {

  BuiltList<BuiltIn>    get   in;

  BuiltUserTags._();

  factory BuiltUserTags([updates(BuiltUserTagsBuilder b)]) = _$BuiltUserTags;

  static Serializer<BuiltUserTags> get serializer => _$builtUserTagsSerializer;
}
```

Comment: why do you want to name it as follows, it is a bad practice to so

Comment: @SamiKanafani i can't change that, because server return this data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

problem solved, thanks to library owner

```
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'in')
BuiltList<BuiltIn> get ins;
```